Command runs normally on command line, but not from script
I'm trying to make a powershell script that will clone a disk to a .img file.
It works if I run each command separately, but doesnt when compiled into a .ps1 file.
$DiskDrives = Gwmi Win32_diskdrive | select DeviceID,BytesPerSector,Index,Caption,InterfaceType,Size,TotalSectors,SerialNumber | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple -Title 'Select Source Drive(s)'
$BaseOutputPath = 'D:\'
$DiskDrives | %{. ('& "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe" if={0} of={1} bs=1M' -f $_.DeviceID,(-join($BaseOutputPath,(-join($Env:ComputerName,$_.Index)),'.img')))}

When run, I get the following output:
. : The term '& "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe" if=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 of=D:\THEIAGO2.img bs=1M' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:19
+ ... rives | %{. ('& "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe" if={0} of={1} b ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (& "C:\Program F...IAGO2.img bs=1M:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

And then running & "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe" if=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 of=D:\THEIAGO2.img bs=1M alone runs as expected.
I've tried everything to fix it, like cd'ind to the exe dir, and running it locally with .\dd.exe but it still doesn't work.

Just curious - have you tried using Start-Process -ArgumentList to see if that works better for passing those args?

Will be easier if you don't make it a one liner, basically you're trying to invoke with the dot sourcing operator . a command that doesn't exist. The call operator & should be outside the string "...", and the string itself should only contain the path to the executable: 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe' then the arguments should be separated from it.
$DiskDrives | ForEach-Object {
    & 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\dd.exe' @(
        "if=$($_.DeviceID)"
        "of=$(-join ($BaseOutputPath, $env:COMPUTERNAME, $_.Index, '.img'))"
        "bs=1M"
    )
}

